# Will the IP address of the Google API host ever change?

Tags: networking, google-api, firewall

We would like to use the Google Translate API from a host which doesn't have open access to the Internet. To setup the firewall rules I would need the list of possible IP addresses for `www.googleapis.com`. It is resolved to different IP addresses depending on the location. It seems to be difficult to create a future proof firewall rule.

Do you know how could I get the list of IP addresses or network ranges for the Google API servers?

Answer (score 0):

The IP addresses used for any given googleapis.com server could change. Google doesn't have just one network block which they host all of their content out of, they have a bunch of them - and they change over time.

There are several ways you could setup your restricted network to allow access to *.googleapis.com without hard-coding IP addresses. I don't know anything about your setup, but I've found that using an internal proxy is often the best bet when you want to allow/restrict access to a domain.